# How to use GDI+ library to decode a jpeg in memory?

Tags: c++, windows, gdi+, gdi

GDI+ provides a Image class, and you can use this class to read a image file with one format and then save this file to another format. But if I want to just decode a jpeg file (already loaded into memory), how can I do it?

Comment: Any reason you can't use WIC (Windows Imaging Component) instead to decode jpegs in memory?  [Here's a link to some starter samples.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee720055(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Thanks for your advice, I wil have a look at WIC.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`SHCreateMemStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb773831(v=vs.85).aspx) and [`Gdiplus::Image::FromStream`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms535371(v=vs.85).aspx)

```
#include <Window.h>
#include <Gdiplus.h>
#include <Shlwapi.h>
#include <atlbase.h>
...
CComPtr<IStream> stream;
stream.Attach(SHCreateMemStream(buf, bufsize));
Gdiplus::Image *image = Gdiplus::Image::FromStream(stream);
```

Where `buf` contains jpeg data (or any other compatible image format) and `bufsize` is the length of that data.

`SHCreateMemStream` needs `"Shlwapi.lib"` library.

Example:

```
void foo(HDC hdc)
{
    //Read jpeg from input file in to buf:
    HANDLE hfile = CreateFile(L"test.jpg", 
        GENERIC_READ, 0, NULL, OPEN_ALWAYS, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (!hfile) return;

    DWORD bufsize = GetFileSize(hfile, NULL);
    BYTE *buf = new BYTE[bufsize];

    DWORD temp;
    ReadFile(hfile, buf, bufsize, &temp, 0);

    //convert buf to IStream    
    CComPtr<IStream> stream;
    stream.Attach(SHCreateMemStream(buf, bufsize));

    //Read from IStream    
    Gdiplus::Bitmap *image = Gdiplus::Bitmap::FromStream(stream);
    if (image)
    {
        Gdiplus::Graphics g(hdc);
        g.DrawImage(image, 0, 0);
        delete image;
    }

    delete[]buf;
    CloseHandle(hfile);
}
```

Edit: easier method as mentioned in comments:

```
IStream* stream = SHCreateMemStream(buf, bufsize);
Gdiplus::Image *image = Gdiplus::Image::FromStream(stream);
...
stream->Release();
```

Comment: That's just what I want. Thanks.

Comment: Actually I had it wrong, it was possibly causing a resource leak. The edited version should fix it. It needs `CComPtr`, do you use Visual Stduio?

Comment: There is no leak in above code, but in previous edit I wasn't using stream.Attach, this leads to memory leak, shown in VS2015 diagnostic tool, and also task manager showed an increase in "private working set memory" because the stream wasn't released.

Comment: It indeed has the problem as you said. but if I don't want to use `CComPtr` (since I don't want to use the MFC framework), I think using `stream->Release()` could also solve this problem. How do you think about?

Comment: You are right, `stream->Release()` is enough. I will edit that.

Comment: It seems that after construction of the Bitmap object, it still rely on the stream interface in consequent drawing, so you can't release the stream, that will be unreasonable. So if you want to release the stream after construction, you must call LockBits and UnlockBits at least once, then the Bitmap will be independent on the stream, you can safely release it.